# How would i recommend products with quantity to customer with Mahout item or user recommendation model

Tags: machine-learning, mahout, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

its distributor level recommendation engine. i am recommending products to distributors.i want to recommend products with quantity also.here i need to recommend past purchased products with quantity and new products with quantity (anticipating the quantity may going to buy by the customer)  to customer.is it possible with Mahout recommendations. can you please guide me to sort it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New products have no ordering history so they cannot be recommended with "collaborative filtering" recommenders. Your best bet is to retrain the recommender often to catch the first orders as soon as possible, then it will recommend them.

As to quantity that is an interesting question. You can't really use the quantity ordered as the preference strength unless the average quantity ordered is the same for all items. If each item has a different "scale" of order you will have to normalize each item's order quantity to get them on the same scale when you train the recommender. Then when you get recommendations map the recommendation strength back to the correct scale for the particular item and that will be your quantity. Just an idea, not sure how well this will work.

Comment: thanks for your reply.i will do R&D on this approach.